# GNU make - map file not created

Tags: makefile, linker, gnu

Below is an image of a make file which executes with no errors,
but no map file is created. Am I missing something out?
Thanks, Amitai

[image]

Comment: Typo: `LDFAGS` --> `LDFLAGS` ?

Comment: Do not post images of text here.  Always copy and paste the text itself.

Comment: Please do not show your code as images. If somebody wants to help you and reproduce what you see (s)he must re-type all this by hand instead of copy-pasting. Insert the code as plain text in your question and format it properly as a block of code (select the portion of text you want to format as code and click the small `{}` icon).

Comment: I didn't mange to enter the code, always got an error, also after formatting, That's why the image is there, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map file wasn't generated due to typo (LDFAGS instead of LDFLAGS),
thanks to G.M. for Detection.